# How to find the next 10 characters after a string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a string **"Create Procedure Test"**. Please find my requirement below:

1- I have to find the string **"Procedure"**.

2- After this I want to search if the particular string say **"dbo"** exists in the next 5 characters after the string **Procedure**.

3- If **dbo** not exists I want to concatenate a string say **MySchema** before string **Test**.

Any Suggestions

Comment: Please look up on Patindex, Charindex and Replace functions in BOL

Comment: @Raj:I know that CHARINDEX('Procedure','Create Procedure Test') can help me to find out if the string exists or not but I am unable to complete the whole cycle.

Comment: OK. Please post your code, as far as you got

Comment: @Raj: I don't have any code for that, I am confuse that how will I process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular `IF` with some simple calculations should do what you need;

```sql
DECLARE @input   NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Create Procedure Test'
DECLARE @keyword NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Procedure'
DECLARE @inject  NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'MySchema.'

DECLARE @index    BIGINT = CHARINDEX(@keyword, @input)
DECLARE @dboindex BIGINT = CHARINDEX('dbo', @input, @index)

IF @dboindex < 1 OR @dboindex - @index - LEN(@keyword) > 5
BEGIN
  SET @input = STUFF(@input, @index + LEN(@keyword) + 1, 0, @inject)
END

SELECT @input
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/16699).

`CHARINDEX` will find where the strings you're looking for exist in the original string, if the positions differ by 5 or less (or `dbo` does not exist at all), it uses `STUFF` to inject the new string at a fixed position after "procedure".

You may want to add some further tolerance as you go, for example it currently only handles a single space after "procedure".

Comment: In your above answer you specify a line 6

It means that CHARINDEX will start searching the dbo from the 8 location from the input. But in case if my string is too long and I only wants to search the dbo from 8th location to 15th location, then what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Expression varchar = 'Create Procedure Test'

If CharIndex('Procedure', @Expression) > 0
Begin
    Declare @Index Int = CharIndex('Procedure', @Expression)

    If CharIndex('dbo', SubString(@Expression, @Index, 5)) = 0
    Begin
        Print Stuff(@Expression, @Index + 10, 0, 'MySchema.')
    End
End
```